# Win8 Loader Animation in CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

I made a copy of Win8 loader animation in CSS (see JSFidle) but it doesn't feel so ... windows like.

```
@-webkit-keyframes win8-dot1 {
    0%   { left: -30px;  }
    26%  { left: 40.625%  }
    52%  { left: 56.25%;  }
    78%  { left: 98.83%; opacity: 1;}
    79%  { opacity: 0;}
    100% { left: 98.83%; opacity: 0; }
}
```

For animation from `26%` to `52%`, I think the change in property `left` should be more. But if I do that, change it to `35%` to `60%` instead of `40.625%` to `56.25%`, the spacing between the dots also increase while transition within `26%` to `52%` which I don't want. (And I don't understand why its happening).

Can anyone come up with better values?

http://jsfiddle.net/nNfAy/

Answer (score 0):

This is a Win8 loader I found and I used on my website.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AoDei